# Device Requirements - iphone ipodtouch -- NOT ipad?

Tags: iphone, submission

Is there a way to specify that the app runs on the iphone, the ipod touch, and NOT the ipad? e.g. modify the info.plist somehow?

Comment: of course, iPhone and iPod touch apps *will* run on an iPad without modification.  Are you trying to prohibit them from running on an iPad??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your project settings, find the key "Targeted Device Family" and chose iPhone. Other choices are iPad and iPhone/iPad.

Don't forget to set this option in every configurations: debug, release and distribution...

Comment: hmm... what am i missing: there is no "targeted device family" in my project settings (or target settings). I see from this link below that it should be in the deployment section, but its just not in the list! i have xcode 3.1.4 (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Running_Applications/running_applications.html)

Comment: Hi TK! To develop for iPad you must have at least SDK 3.2! 

With your SDK 3.1.4 you have no setting to change; your app will be for iPhone and iPod Touch only by default. 

It will run on iPad but will not be a native iPad app with full screen support.

Comment: If you REALLY want to BLOCK the iPad from running your app at all, there is another way, but I warn you nobody wants this!

Comment: oh good to know! I was worried when I uploaded it in itunes connect because it automatically said "ok for ipodtouch, iphone and ipad". (Also I was secretly hoping that by not having it be ipad-compatible it might get routed to a smaller pool of apps to be reviewed.... My app is time-sensitive...). Thanks for your help!